# Is it possible to force TPL to always use the same thread indexes across different Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I have a memory problem with the use of Parallel.For.

Is it possible to force TPL to always use the same thread indexes across different Parallel.For?

Even when I use `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount` in all different Parallel.For,   TPL doesn't exactly use the same thread pool between two successive Parallel.For.
I have memory issues because of this problem.

I don't understand why if my `Environment.ProcessorCount = 2`, TPL doesn't create at the beginning only 2 threads and reuse it for all my successive Parallel.For. This is my goal.

How can I manage that?

Comment: How do you know that your memory issues are specifically because of this problem and not due to something else, or perhaps a combination of factors?

Comment: Are you even sure your problem is CPU bound? "TPL doesn't create at the beginning only 2 threads and reuse it for all my successive Parallel.For. This is my goal." No. Your goal is to write software that runs on hardware. How many processors in your machine should not affect your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

If you want manual control of threads, TPL isn't the correct abstraction. Use System.Threading directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, but you need to configure the parallel loop with a custom [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler), which is [tricky](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/). This `TaskScheduler` will be effectively a custom thread pool with a fixed number of threads, completely unrelated from the built-in [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). The responsibility of starting and terminating these threads will be completely up to you. Here is a minimal implementation of such a pool:

```
public class CustomThreadPool : TaskScheduler, IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Task> _queue;
    private readonly Thread[] _threads;

    public CustomThreadPool(int threadsCount)
    {
        _queue = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
        _threads = Enumerable.Range(0, threadsCount).Select(_ => new Thread(() =>
        {
            foreach (var task in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                TryExecuteTask(task);
        })).ToArray();
        Array.ForEach(_threads, t => t.IsBackground = true);
        Array.ForEach(_threads, t => t.Start());
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task) => _queue.Add(task);

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task,
        bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(_threads, Thread.CurrentThread) < 0) return false;
        return TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => _threads.Length;
    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks() => _queue;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
        Array.ForEach(_threads, t => t.Join());
        _queue.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You could use it with a [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for) loop like this:

```
using CustomThreadPool customThreadPool = new(threadsCount: 2);
ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    TaskScheduler = customThreadPool,
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = customThreadPool.MaximumConcurrencyLevel,
};
Parallel.For(1, 10, options, i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"i: {i}, Thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
});
```

Sample output:

```
i: 5, Thread #4
i: 1, Thread #5
i: 2, Thread #5
i: 6, Thread #4
i: 3, Thread #5
i: 7, Thread #4
i: 4, Thread #5
i: 8, Thread #4
i: 9, Thread #5
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j2jQtf).

As long as you use the same `CustomThreadPool` instance, all your parallel loops will be running on the same threads #4 and #5.